# Upload converted (from Layout) and not saved in internal storage, image to Firebase. In other words, upload <LinearLayout> as image. Android Studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

[Video with this project](https://streamable.com/32np6d)

I have created a ImageView with a backround (png) picture, and EditText. So both of them are inside the LinerLayout, so if i am entering values to the EditText, i will have a completely diferent image.
I am doing this, because the LinearLayout represents a "credit card" (as a backround of ImageView), and diferent values (as values in EditText).

I was able to convert the LinearLayout into an image with Bitmap, so every time i am entering diferent user's values in EditText by pressing PREVIEW i am generating a user credit card.

The problem is that now i want to upload THAT specific image into my Firebase. I already added the dependencies and tried to upload from my Local Intern Memory some random pictures which works, but i haven't figured yet how to upload the converted image which is actually a normal image into the firebase, without having to store the image into my internal storage.

I tried to combine the upload from internal memory with my actual converting image class, but this process requires Uri which (converted LinearLayout) image doesn't have.

**This is my java class:**

```
    public class DashboardAddBanking extends AppCompatActivity {
    
    EditText e1, e2, e3, e4, e5, e6, e7, e8, e9;
    TextView t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6;
    Button preview, save;
    ImageView credit_card, imgResultImage;
    RelativeLayout layout_view;

    Bitmap image;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard_add_banking);


        e1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et1); //Code 1
        e2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et2); //Code 2
        e3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et3); //Code 3
        e4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et4); //Code 4
        e5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et5); //name
        e6 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et6); //month
        e7 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et7); //year
        e8 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et8); //cvv
        e9 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et9); //bank name

        t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.card_number);
        t2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.card_holder);
        t3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.month);
        t4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.year);
        t5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cvv);
        t6 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bankname);

        preview = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_preview_credit_card);
        save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_save_credit_card);
        credit_card = findViewById(R.id.credit_card);
        imgResultImage = findViewById(R.id.imgResultImage);
        layout_view = findViewById(R.id.rl1);

        //Preview card
        preview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.push_down);
                RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl1);
                relativeLayout.setAnimation(animation);

                String code1, code2, code3, code4;
                String name, month, year, cvv, bankname;

                code1 = e1.getText().toString();
                code2 = e2.getText().toString();
                code3 = e3.getText().toString();
                code4 = e4.getText().toString();

                t1.setText(code1 + "\t" + code2 + "\t" + code3 + "\t" + code4 + "\t");

                name = e5.getText().toString();
                t2.setText(name);
                month = e6.getText().toString();
                t3.setText(month);
                year = e7.getText().toString();
                t4.setText(year);
                cvv = e8.getText().toString();
                t5.setText(cvv);
                bankname = e9.getText().toString();
                t6.setText(bankname);

            }
        });

        //Convert layout to image
        save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                image = getBitmapFromView(layout_view);
                imgResultImage.setImageBitmap(image);

            }
        });


    }

    private Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View view) {
        //Define a bitmap with the same size as the view
        Bitmap returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        //Bind a canvas to it
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(returnedBitmap);
        //Get the view's background
        Drawable bgDrawable = view.getBackground();
        if (bgDrawable != null) {
            //has background drawable, then draw it on the canvas
            bgDrawable.draw(canvas);
        } else {
            //does not have background drawable, then draw white background on the canvas
            canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
        }
        // draw the view on the canvas
        view.draw(canvas);
        //return the bitmap
        return returnedBitmap;
    }
}
```

**This is my XML file**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".dashboard.banking.DashboardAddBanking">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/credit_card"
            android:layout_width="335dp"
            android:layout_height="185dp"
            android:background="@drawable/credit_card"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bankname"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Bank name"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/card_number"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/bankname"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
            android:id="@+id/card_number"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Cardholder"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/card_number"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
            android:id="@+id/card_holder"
            />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/card_holder"
            android:layout_below="@+id/card_number"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/month"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="06"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="15sp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/mm"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="MM"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="12sp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/div"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/ll1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/card_number"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:text="/"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/div"
            android:layout_below="@+id/card_number"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/year"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="21"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="15sp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/yy"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="YY"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="12sp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="CVV"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/ll2"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/card_number"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="15sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cvv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=" -  -  -"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/ll2"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/card_number"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="12sp"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/rl2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rl1"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="16 digit number"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:textColor="@color/primaryText"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:id="@+id/tv1"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="XXXX"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:maxLength="4"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:textColorHint="@color/mainText"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et2"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/et1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="XXXX"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:maxLength="4"
            android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:textColorHint="@color/mainText"/>
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et3"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/et2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="XXXX"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:maxLength="4"
            android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:textColorHint="@color/mainText"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et4"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/et3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="XXXX"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:maxLength="4"
            android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:textColorHint="@color/mainText"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Cardholder Name"
            android:id="@+id/tv2"
            android:layout_below="@id/et1"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:textColor="@color/primaryText"
            android:textSize="12sp"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Card holder"
            android:id="@+id/et5"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv2"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:textColorHint="@color/mainText"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Expire"
            android:id="@+id/tv3"
            android:layout_below="@id/et5"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:textColor="@color/primaryText"
            android:textSize="12sp"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="MM"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:maxLength="2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv3"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:textColorHint="@color/mainText"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/et6"
            android:hint="YY"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:maxLength="2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv3"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:textColorHint="@color/mainText"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="CVV"
            android:layout_below="@id/et6"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:textColor="@color/primaryText"
            android:textSize="12sp"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="XXX"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:maxLength="3"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv4"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:textColorHint="@color/mainText"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Bank name"
            android:layout_below="@id/et6"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tv4"
            android:layout_marginStart="200dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:textColor="@color/primaryText"
            android:textSize="12sp"/>
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/et8"
            android:hint="Your Bank"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv5"
            android:layout_marginStart="180dp"
            android:textColorHint="@color/mainText"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_preview_credit_card"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rl2"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_save_round"
        android:text="Preview"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="15sp" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgResultImage"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/btn_preview_credit_card"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rl2"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_save_credit_card"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rl2"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imgResultImage"
        android:layout_marginStart="250dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_save_round"
        android:text="Save"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="15sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Could you please help me?
I would be so gratefull as i am trying to find an idea couple of days now.
[Video with this project](https://streamable.com/32np6d)

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted almost **500** lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.

Comment: If you found a viable solution, most likely you should add it as an answer, so future visitors can see it.

Comment: @AlexMamo, already did. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a solution. I have converted the image in Base64 String. So easy upload that String in Firebase Realtime Database. Then i am retrieving it again in base64 format. After that i am decoding the base64 format image into a bitmap image, and then i am showing it to the user.

First of all, you have to convert your image to Bitmap by calling the next method:

```
yourBitMappedImage = getBitmapFromFrontView(yourImageViewImage);
```

-- Get BitMap from View --

```
private Bitmap getBitmapFromFrontView(View view) {
    //Define a bitmap with the same size as the view
    Bitmap frontReturnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    //Bind a canvas to it
    Canvas frontCanvas = new Canvas(frontReturnedBitmap);
    //Get the view's background
    Drawable frontBGDrawable = view.getBackground();
    if (frontBGDrawable != null) {
        //has background drawable, then draw it on the canvas
        frontBGDrawable.draw(frontCanvas);
    } else {
        //does not have background drawable, then draw white background on the canvas
        frontCanvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    }
    // draw the view on the canvas
    view.draw(frontCanvas);
    //return the bitmap
    return frontReturnedBitmap;
}
```

-- Declare image --

```
ImageView image =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
```

-- Encode image to Base64 String--

```
ByteArrayOutputStream frontbaos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitMappedFrontImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, frontbaos);
    byte[] frontImageBytes = frontbaos.toByteArray();
    String base64FrontImage = Base64.encodeToString(frontImageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
   System.out.println("Here is your Base64 String:"+ base64FrontImage);
```

-- Decode image from Base64 string to Bitmap --

```
 ByteArrayOutputStream frontbaos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] frontImageBytes = frontbaos.toByteArray();
    frontImageBytes = Base64.decode(String.valueOf(base64FrontImage), Base64.DEFAULT);
    Bitmap decodedFrontImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(frontImageBytes, 0, frontImageBytes.length);
    image.setImageBitmap(decodedFrontImage );
```